# if/else statement on ajax success

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I trying to get an counterstat for unread Messages:
The PHP-Code (BubbleStat.php) looks like this:

```
$totalMsg = $mysql->totalRows("SELECT msg_id from messages WHERE msg_opened = 0 AND msg_receiver = '".$_SESSION["ActiveUserSessionId"]."'");
    echo $totalMsgs;
```

The jQuery code i have this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '/BubbleStat.php',
cache: false,
success: function(html)
    {
        $("#Bubble_Msg").show(); 
    } 
});
```

So how i can get the counter for unread Msgs in #Bubble_Msg ?
It would be nice if the Counter have'nt unread messages to hide the div #Bubble_Msg.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
success: function(html) {

    // Check if the Counter have unread messages
    if (parseInt(html) > 0) {
        $("#Bubble_Msg").text(html).show();
    }
    else {
        $("#Bubble_Msg").hide();
    }
}​
```

Comment: Thank you Palash, the if-switch was exactly I needed!

Answer (score 1):

As in... [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text)?

```
$("#Bubble_Msg").text(html).show();
```

If the `html`-named variable actually contans HTML, then... [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

use it this way:

```
success: function(html)
{
    $("#Bubble_Msg").html(html).show(); 
} //-----------------------^^----------this html is the param passed in the 
  //-----------------------------------success function
```

Comment: Oh Thanks musa just did it in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your PHP script return a JSON response.

It may look like a lot of code but definitely worth it if you need to add complexity into your script.

1- ensure that the response won't be cached whatever happens:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
```

2- json type header:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

3- compute every values you need to know:

```
$totalMsg = $mysql->totalRows("SELECT msg_id from messages WHERE msg_opened = 0 AND msg_receiver = '".$_SESSION["ActiveUserSessionId"]."'");
```

4- build an array with them:

```
$response = array(
    'total' => $totalMsg,
    'extra' => 'extra value (if needed)'
);
```

5- echo in json encoding:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

After then, you could access your value with jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '/BubbleStat.php',
cache: false,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(jsonData)
    {
        if (jsonData.total != null && jsonData.total != undefined)
        {                
            $("#Bubble_Msg").text(jsonData.total).show();
        } 
    } 
});
```

The problem looks easier if you get variables to work with.

Comment: Thats very extra!! Thank you so much. This helps mo too to fix another problem i had ;-)